# I have an appium test program that works perfectly fine on google nexus 5 but not in Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 with android 5.0.2

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I have an appium test program that works perfectly fine on google nexus 5 with android 5.1.1 but when I configure the test for Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 with android 5.0.2  the program starts running, the app gets installed and opens up fine but as soon as the first page comes up, nothing happens anymore.

Following the Desired capabilities and the first test

```
@Test
public void test0() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

File app = new File("C:\\Users\\Samila\\Documents\\Mobile_Research\\Apk\\android-debug.apk");


        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();
        caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        caps.setCapability("deviceName","samsung-sm_t530nu");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
        caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "landscape");
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());


        aadr = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);      


    }





    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {

        //Wait until application open correctly
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(aadr, 40);




        //Locate URL , User Name and Password
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("android.widget.EditText")));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("test.orangehrm.com")));
        MobileElement url = (MobileElement) aadr.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).get(0);
        MobileElement userName = (MobileElement) aadr.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).get(1);
        MobileElement password = (MobileElement) aadr.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).get(2);
        System.out.println(url);System.out.println(userName);System.out.println(password);System.out.println(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            MobileElement test = (MobileElement) aadr.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).get(i);
            System.out.println(i+" "+ test.getId());
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        //Test 1- Press Login button with the Empty URL, User Name & Password
        url.click();
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){aadr.sendKeyEvent(67);}
        aadr.hideKeyboard();

        //Wait till button is available on the screen
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("android.widget.Button")));
        MobileElement loginBtn = (MobileElement)aadr.findElements(By.className("android.widget.Button")).get(1);

        //Tap the Login button
        TouchAction btn = new TouchAction(aadr);
        btn.tap(loginBtn).perform();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("android.view.View")));

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        MobileElement warninigMsg = (MobileElement) aadr.findElements(By.className("android.view.View")).get(9);

        //Assert whether Username empty warning message is coming or not
        assertEquals("Username is Empty",warninigMsg.getAttribute("name"));
```

Comment: Any exceptions on console logs? any warnings/Errors in Appium logs?
Giving Appium logs will be useful to debug.

Comment: try setting auto accept alerts to true and see if it's hanging because of that